# Android Music Sales/Player HTML5 App - Best dev platform?

Tags: cordova, titanium, appcelerator

I'm currently in the process of developing a HTML5/javascript app for Android - my initial plan was to use Phonegap as I have years of js/front-end dev expereince and no Android/Java dev experience - but I've just been reading about Appcelerator and wonder whether this is a better solution?

The app will need to process/render a lot of xml to display it's catalogue, I have the back-end in place to stagger this process - but I need a solid platform that will give the fastest experience here.

I also need to integrate a music player and I cant find any information on displaying mp3 id3 information using phonegap?  (and i'm struggling to even display files from the sd card).

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it yet but you could look at:

http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net//libraries/id3/

for reading ID3 tags using JavaScript.

What is your problem with displaying images from the SD Card? The src attribute of your img tag should start like "file:///sdcard/...". Note the triple / before starting the file path.

Comment: Hi Simon - I'm struggling with the filesystem api - I cant get past the:  
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail); 

part - No idea what i'm doing wrong - I've added several mp3 files to the sd card but it doesn't seem to return anything!

Comment: I'm developing for Android SDK 2.1 by the way

Comment: What error are you seeing when you can't get past onFileSystemSuccess?